# urlrewriting and mod_auth_token (apache module)

Tags: mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite a URL like:

my target:
`http://monsite.com/my_other_files/55e35373739efc04a34d408c7c28a7b9/50e084f6/my_video.mp4`

my real path:
`http://monsite.com/my_files/55e35373739efc04a34d408c7c28a7b9/50e084f6/my_video.mp4`

my code in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^my_other_files/([a-zA-z0-9_-]/[a-zA-z0-9_-]/[a-zA-z0-9_-]*)$
   my_files/$1/$2/$3 [QSA,L]
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there, to be honest.

You need the leading `/` in the rewrite rule and you aren't allowing multiple characters in each path component.

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/my_other_files/([0-9a-f]+)/([0-9a-f]+)/([a-z0-9_.-]+)$
    /my_files/$1/$2/$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I added `[NC]` to the end, so that it's not case-sensitive, and added `.` to the last group, so it would match something like `my_video.mp4`

Also, it look like your path components are all hexadecimal, so I simplified it some. If that's not an accurate assumption on my part, try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/my_other_files/([a-z0-9_-]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+)/([a-z0-9_.-]+)$
    /my_files/$1/$2/$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

In both cases, I've added a line-break for legibility; that shouldn't be there in your actual rule.

The alternative is just to accept anything in `/my_other_files/` and redirect it to `/myfiles/`, in which case you could just use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/my_other_files/(.+)$ /my_files/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I hope you get this sorted!  :o)

Comment: thank you for the quick response, but I have 404 error for my link

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled? It's worth adding `RewriteEngine on` above that rule and looking through the [`mod_rewrite` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html), I'd suggest...